ASP.NET dropdown list using Virtual Code pulling data from SSMS
I am trying write a string for dropdown list however I keep coming across this error.
I wanna figure out a way to get around the error in order for my dropdown list to show on my dashboard.
My Visual Studio is linked to my SQL Server Management Studio. I am using C# for coding on the Visual Studio and C# uses String for letters and SSMS uses Varchar, this is where error emanates from.
I have uploaded a screenshot that shows the error
error

When you asked your question, you were told "Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and not as images), and format them appropriately." Please follow the instructions when posting your questions, as otherwise you are likely to receive down and/or close votes; meaning your question is far less likely to be answered.

Seems that the problem is not in the dataTypes
(String in C# and Varchar in SQL), are compatible, and this would not usually cause a NullReferenceException. When you retrieve data from the database, the ADO.NET framework handles the conversion from SQL data types to .NET data types.
The problem lies within the configuration or the mainconn variable itself
make sure that there is a connection string named "DefaultConnection" in your Web.config or App.config file.
it should look something like this:
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>

If ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"] returns null, then it is likely that there is a problem with your configuration file or the way the configuration is being read.
